# Can't get element inside controller in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get an element inside an AngularJS controller like this:

```
var imageInput = document.getElementById("myImage");
```

It doesn't work, the element is null. However if I move the statement to a function that I bound with `ng-click` it works. Why? and how do I fix it?

Comment: We really need more info about what you actually want to achieve. DOM manipulation in controllers is totally against Angular's goals. Kitten will die and 7 years of pain and hunger will come over you if you violate that principle ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not rendered for that time. If you write all code, we'll suggest better alternative than working with dom in controller (it's no good for you :) )

Answer (score 0):

Like Karaxuna said, it has not been rendered yet.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could use a directive to add behavior to your element : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Add some code so we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not only it may have not been rendered in your dom, but also you should inject the `$window` in your controller and then access the document like this:

```
    var myCtrl = function($scope,$window) {
       Var document = $window.document
       ...
    }
```

But you should seek a better way to manipulate your DOM instead of doing so in your controller (e.g. Writing a directive)